# Using fgets() without predefined buffer

Tags: c, buffer, stdin, fgets

I need to ask one more question about reading from the stdin.
I am reading a huge trunk of lines from the stdin, but it is definitely unknown which is the size of every line. So I don't want to have a buffer like 50Mio just for a file having lines of three char and than a file using these 50 Mio per line.
So at the moment I am having this code:

```
int cur_max = 2047;
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * cur_max);
int length = 0;

while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL) {
    //do something with str
    //for example printing
    printf("%s",str);
}

free(str);
```

So I am using fgets for every line and I do have a first size of 2047 char per line.
My plan is to increase the size of the buffer (str) when a line hits the limit. So my idea is to count the size with length and if the current length is bigger than cur_max then I am doubling the cur_max.
The idea comes from here [Read line from file without knowing the line length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length)
I am currently not sure how to do this with fgets because I think fgets is not doing this char by char so I don't know the moment when to increase the size.

Comment: You might take a look at the standard [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) function.

Comment: Given `char *str`, just what do you think `sizeof( str )` returns?

Comment: I think sizeof(str) gives the current size of str. But is this increasing for every character?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` -> `sizeof(char) * cur_max`. `sizeof(str)` is the size of a _pointer_ on your platform (most likely 4 or 8), not the size of the buffer where it points to. Remember: pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand In your code, `sizeof(str)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` which is probably either 4 or 8.  You want something more like `fgets(str, cur_max, stdin)`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689288/why-does-sizeof-not-work-for-pointer-arrays .

Comment: OT:  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.   Multiplying any value by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression from the parameter to `malloc()`

Comment: Note: robust code does not give unlimited allocation possibilities to external forces as the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length) suggests. Defensive code have an upper bound of reasonable _line_ length.  Lines exceeding some threshold are best to be considered hostile and should be rejected. Do not write code to be the next hacker exploit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Incorrect code

`sizeof(str)` is the size of a pointer, like 2, 4  or 8 bytes.  Pass to `fgets()` the size of the memory pointed to by `str`. [@Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit)

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * cur_max);
...
// while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL
while(fgets(str, cur_max, stdin) != NULL
```

### Environmental limits

*Text files* and `fgets()` are not the portable solution for reading excessively long lines.

> An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256  C11 §7.21.2 9

So once the line length exceeds `BUFSIZ - 2`, code is on its own as to if the C standard library functions can handle a *text file*.

So either read the data as binary, use other libraries that insure the desired functionality, or rely on hope.

Note: `BUFSIZ` defined in `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it

Answer (score 1):

POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) ([`man 3 getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) is available in almost all operating systems' C libraries (the only exception I know of is Windows). A loop to read lines of any length is

```
char    *line_ptr = NULL;
size_t   line_max = 0;
ssize_t  line_len;

while (1) {

    line_len = getline(&line_ptr, &line_max, stdin);
    if (line_len == -1)
        break;

    /* You now have 'line_len' chars at 'line_ptr',
       but it may contain embedded nul chars ('\0').
       Also, line_ptr[line_len] == '\0'.
    */
}

/* Discard dynamically allocated buffer; allow reuse later. */
free(line_ptr);
line_ptr = NULL;
line_max = 0;
```

There is also a related function `getdelim()`, that takes an extra parameter (specified before the stream), used as an end-of-record marker. It is particularly useful in Unixy/POSIXy environments when reading file names from e.g. standard input, as you can use nul itself (`'\0'`) as the separator (see e.g. [`find -print0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) or [`xargs -0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)), allowing correct handling for all possible file names.

If you use Windows, or if you have text files with varying newline conventions (not just `'\n'`, but any of `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `"\r\n"`, or `"\n\r"`), you can use my [`getline_universal()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50252414/1475978) function implementation from another of my answers.  It differs from standard `getline()` and `fgets()` in that the newline is not included in the line it returns; it is also left in the stream and consumed/ignored by the *next* call to `getline_universal()`. If you use `getline_universal()` to read each line in a file or stream, it will work as expected.